# Bootstrap iPad/iPad mini wider in portrait

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have being tearing my hair out trying to get a fix for this, the site is built with Twitter Bootstrap and is responsive, and works fine on all devices apart from iPad & iPad mini in portrait where it is always wider that the devices screen.

I know that there is a problem on device rotation with iOS devices, but this is on page load in portrait.

Any advice would be great, I am not sure if it is a problem with Bootstrap or something I have done.

http://bodysgallen.ws-django.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

you may need to make a new set of responsive CSS to fit that screen size. 
EG you have something like this @media (max-width: 979px)  & @media (min-width: 1200px). You might need to add another one in between to handle the size of the iPad on portrait.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the problem is related specifically to iPads. Something odd is happening with your grid at a viewport of 769px - 945px (approx).  It's not responding correctly.

If you check validation results for the page there are a number of errors which aren't too important but at the end there are two I would fix, an unclosed container div and a body tag that was already closed.  http://bit.ly/11fKdhG

While these 2 errors aren't necessarily the cause of the problem, I think you want fix them first.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your reply, The large list of errors is down to it being a CMS, and I failed to see those 2, so thanks for that.

Comment: I don't see those 2 errors showing now either ... go figure ;-) I still think there's something up with your grid though. I'll look into it more when I have some time.

Comment: Yea I fixed those 2 :) - Thanks, I THINK that it all may be down to the width of some divs being in pixels, will post back with my results(if any).

Comment: > I THINK that it all may be down to the width of some divs being in pixels .... It may well be. To me it looks like something is forcing a div to be wider that it should be. Either because of a hard wired width setting, or maybe padding / margins

Comment: It's looking to me like you might have solved it now. What was it?